# On RabbitMQ Cluster - node shutdown - Celery workers hang out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, celery, amazon-elb

We have configured a **rabbitmq cluster** with a mirrored queue.
All instructions were taken from *http://www.rabbitmq.com/*

All is well and working ok.

**The configuration is**:

- 3 nodes
- 1 master & 2 slaves
- mirrored queue
- each node on separated EC2 (AWS)
- ELB with the above 3 instances
- Celery connected to the ELB

**The problem**:

when we shutdown one of the nodes,
The celery workers hang out.

We believe it is something related to the AWS ELB configuration but with no luck.

Anyone?

Comment: ELB have removed the node from load-balancer, (health check)?

Comment: @ant31 - yes it does